# How to represent data objects gradually getting augmented in a pipeline

Tags: design, design-patterns, scala

I'm working on a Scala data-processing program.  Essentially we start with a collection of many small data objects, say, `(eventId: String, basicInfo: Basic)` and gradually filter out some objects and add more information by joining the original collections with other data sources (typically on the `eventId` field), or by computing new fields as functions of existing fields.

Now, I'm having a certain amount of trouble designing this properly.  It's rather adhoc now - the original data item is modeled as `case class FirstStage(eventId: String, basicInfo: Basic)` and subsequent stages are modeled compositionally: `case class SecondStage(first: FirstStage, someOtherId: Long)`, and so on.  This results in rather ugly chains of accessors (e.g `third.second.first.basicInfo`) and makes the code very difficult to modify.  For example, we might want to change some function `persist:ThirdStage =>` to operate instead or additionally on `SecondStage`, but the lack of polymorphism in the design makes that pretty hard.

One idea might be to start out with the terminal stage, initially set all its fields to null, and gradually fill them out, but it seems as if it would be difficult to keep track of what happens when.  Or, we could ditch the case classes in order to have `SecondStage` extend `FirstStage` and so on, but I think it's probable that the program will lose its linearity in the next few months, which will make the inheritance approach rather clunky.

Comment: Without seeing any code it's hard to point out exactly what's wrong and provide a proper solution, but naming things like `SecondStage` is a code smell. Is there any reason you can't just use tuples?

Comment: Normally if you want to compose foo, bar and baz on some data, you just call foo(bar(baz(data))). But a few bits of your question imply that you want foo to have access to the pre-baz data as well as the post-bar data. Is that true? Does it *need* to have that kind of access? (trying to remove that need would be my first move)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the State monad from scalaz -> http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/State.html

The data type would be State[Stage, Data] where Stage consists of your stages and data the value that accompanies the current stage.

```
case class Stage(id: String, someStateInfo: String)
case class Data(someData: String, anotherData: String)
```

Create a state:

```
State[Stage, Data] { 
   case Stage(id, someStateInfo) => 

   // some function that inspects stateInfo and generates a newData
   val newData = if (someStateInfo == ...) Data("x", "y")
                 else Data("a", "b")
   val newState = State(generateNewId(), generateNewStateInfo())

   // return new state and new data
   (newState, newData)
}
```

The question is a bit vague and I am not sure if this is what you want, but hopefully it will get you to explore the link I provided and be willing to bend your mind with this functional programming pattern (Monad + State Monad).